# How to understand spark execution time without access to spark history UI?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, cassandra

I have written pyspark job , and my job is running longer . I want to analyze job execution  and fix the code part that is causing slowness. Due to access issue over spark history ui I can not analyze job plan. Hence I have to do some tricks around the code and understand at what section spark is consuming more time.
I have tried to run count on data-frame but it seems this is not that much help to understand job slowness.
below are step I am doing on my code:

**step-1 : read from cassandra table:**

```
cassandra_data = spark_session.read \
        .format('org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra') \
        .options(table=table, keyspace=keyspace) \
        .load()
    return data
```

**step -2 : add a column in data-frame read from cassandra that has value of md5 over entire row .**

```
data_wth_hash = prepare_data_md5(cassandra_data)
data_wth_hash.cache()
data_wth_hash.count()
```

**step -3 : write into aws s3 folder .**
Job is taking much more time while writing into s3 ,  I do not have access to spark history ui to understand where it is consuming more time.

Comment: if you are using the standard output committers, the time to write into s3 is dominated by rename calls, which are O(data)., Switch to an s3-aware committer

Comment: I am using s3a  implementation .

Comment: you may be using the S3A code, but you still need to look at the hadoop s3a documentation and see how to switch to an S3 aware committer, I'm not going to repeat it here as its covered in other questions